# iOS equivalent to MacOS NSAttributedString initWithRTF

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, nsattributedstring

What is an iOS equivalent to MacOS NSAttributedString initWithRTF ?

The Application Kit extends Foundation’s NSAttributedString class by adding support for RTF, RTFD, and HTML (with or without attachments), graphics attributes (including font and ruler attributes), methods for drawing attributed strings, and methods for calculating significant linguistic units.

```
- (id)initWithRTF:(NSData *)rtfData documentAttributes:(NSDictionary **)docAttributes
```

I need to process a short stream of RTF data in an iOS application.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent in iOS. The iOS version of `NSAttributedString` has only the functionality needed by CoreText, and CoreText itself has only the functionality needed by the UI classes, and this does not include RTF processing.

As far as I know, at least as of 5.0, `UIWebView` is the only way to process RTF. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html. That may have changed with 5.1, because some of Apple's other apps seem to handle rich text now (but then again, those apps may have just changed from `UITextView` to `UIWebView`…).

---

`UIWebView` doesn't give you any way to access the attributed text from the RTF, because the web view never *builds* attributed text—instead, it builds HTML and CSS.

The good news is that this HTML and CSS is available in the DOM. At least for some types, this isn't true—all you see is an opaque wrapper that gets rendered by some magic code inside WebKit that you can't access—but RTF is not one of those types.

Using [Safari Web Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006515), I opened up [a sample RTF file](http://thewalter.net/stef/software/rtfx/sample.rtf) on my iPhone, and looked at the DOM. It's full of nodes like this:

```
<span class="s2"><span class="bumpedFont16">m a test file. This is some </span></span>
<span class="s3"><span class="bumpedFont16">bold</span></span>
```

… where those classes are defined with inline `<style>` tags immediately before the tag they're first used in.

So, if walk the nodes that have text, that text is like an attributed character range (although if you actually want the start and end indices you'll need to count them up yourself…), and its computed style is roughly like an attribute dictionary. Of course "roughly like" isn't "identical"; a computed style looks like this:

```
direction: ltr; display: inline; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold; height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px; text-align: left; width: auto;
```

So, not actually compatible with NSAttributedString, and not nearly as nice (unless your end goal is to create HTML, of course)… but at least something you can use.

Comment: thank you. I managed to get the plain text out of rtf file using UIWebView and a stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method with document.documentElement.innerText argument

Comment: @radvan72: Clever solution. I was thinking that UIWebView is no good unless all you want to do is display the RTF, but you actually _can_ get the contents that way…

Comment: Great, thank you! That's probably the best thing on Apple's developer site I've ever read. Would you know if there's any way to get the attributed text from the RTF, perhaps through the WebView?

Comment: @JohnK: As I understand it, there _is_ no attributed text to get. There may be HTML and CSS, in which case you ought to be able to get it out of the DOM, or there may be some kind of `<Object>` that's rendered by private code that you can't access (as with PDF files on desktop Safari); I don't know which.

Comment: @JohnK: Actually, from a quick test, it looks like at least RTF is parsed into HTML and CSS. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that, abarnert. I ran across something interesting about `NSHTMLWriter`, which unfortunately seems to be a private class, so no-go.

Comment: @JohnK: Looks interesting. From [here](https://twitter.com/Cocoanetics/status/280010294439313408), it looks like the HTML I'm seeing is exactly what `NSHTMLWriter` generates from an `NSAttributedString`. Which implies that they're converting the RTF to a full OS X-style `NSAttributedString` object using some private method (which you'd expect, but it's nice to have proof). You could track that down, or just swizzle `-[NSHTMLWriter initWithAttributedString:]` so you can intercept the attrstrings on the way through… Unless, of course, you want your app to be in the App Store instead of Cydia.