# MutableAttributedString Works in iOS 7 but not iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, nsattributedstring

I've been working with an application that creates an `NSAttributedString` from an `.rtf` file. I've been testing this app on iOS 7 with no problems. However, when I tested this app on iOS 6, I get this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteAttributedString initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a77010'`

Here's the code that I have:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *stringURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Text" withExtension:@".rtf"];
NSAttributedString *myAttributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:stringURL options:nil documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
```

Answer (score 4):

From the Apple Docs - [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithFileURL%3aoptions%3adocumentAttributes%3aerror%3a)

`initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:` is only available in iOS 7.0

EDIT: As mentioned in comments

If you want to test whether a selector is available on an object or protocol (that inherits from NSObject) then you can check using `[object respondsToSelector:@selector()]` in this case

```
NSAttributedString *myAttributedText;
if ([myAttributedText respondsToSelector:@selector(initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:)]) {
    myAttributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:stringURL options:nil documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
}
else {
    // Init some other way
}
```

Comment: You can, of course, test whether the new interface is supported, and, if not, use a fallback approach.

Comment: Ok, @Evan that makes sense. So, that begs the question: How do I load the `rtf` file in iOS 6?

Comment: @Cody unfortunately this isn't something I have ever had to work with so I am unsure on the possibilities. Your best bet would be searching for a library that does it. [StackOverflow article that might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920678/ios-equivalent-to-macos-nsattributedstring-initwithrtf)

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because the method you're calling

`initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:`

was introduces only in iOS 7.0.

You can check the iOS 6.1 to iOS 7.0 API Diffs here: 
[iOS 6.1 to iOS 7.0 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013203)

And here, specifically, you can see the [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:)

Calling a method that doesn't exist will cause your app to crash. You should set your deployment target to 7.0 or use something like `ifdefs` to avoid calling this method in earlier versions ([reference link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406622/ifdef-else-endif-choose-ios-sdk-version-and-function)).